# ZPL Programming - reset settings on each print job

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Zebra ZPL label printers carry over the print commands from print job to print job. So if you send a `^FWR` command that rotates a label, all future jobs will be rotated, so you have to reset the orientation to `^FWN` if you want to have the next label be printed in portrait mode.

Is there a way to automatically reset the 'standard' settings on a Zebra on each print job? So settings from the previous job don't carry over to the next job? I want every zpl file I send to the printer to be printed exactly the same, regardless of what was printed prior.

Or is there a default set of commands that I can send that reset the orientation, fonts, position, dpi, measurements, etc?

There's a command that does a power-on/factory reset, but I don't want to do that on every label print.

Comment: What model printer? In my past, I have included every command for every label. Commands for thermal transfer/direct print method, standard/flipped orientation, etc.. If you are using XML printing, you can set those commands in the template ZPL file.

Comment: ZP-505. I'm printing labels generated by third parties that don't always reset the printer to a known good state (i.e. reset the text flow from vertical to horizontal)

Comment: Have you tried doing a replace function on the ZPL strings to remove the commands you don't want used?

Comment: No - but I'm not really following. I'm printing all sorts of ZPL labels, generated by different sources. Some of the labels have commands like `^PO` that change the label's orientation, which screws up subsequent labels that assume that the label's orientation is the device's default. I'm not sure what I would remove from the label here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually reset all unwanted settings.

This works for me

```
^PON^LH0,0^FWN
```

.

```
FWN resets field orientation
LH resets the offset
PO resets print orientation
```

Not sure if all of those are needed and/or others would be needed for you too. In my particular case, I did not need FWN.

My printing got messed up when pasting some sample ZPL to the printer. Next 30 labels had orientation and offset changed making them unusable. So I just have above command in beginning of my labels now.

You might specifically have to reset other settings too.

Comment: LH and PO were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can send ZPL Before or After a label you want to print, add the commands you want, like `^PO` outside of the begin `^XA`/end `^XZ` label. It should change it until another similar command is set.